# Swift - Get an array of strings from JSON using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

```
[
  {
    "content": "Hello!",
    "images": [
      {
        "url": "http://url1.com"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://url2.com"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://url3.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I get an array of image urls using `SwiftyJSON`?

This is what I tried and did not work.

```
for (key, subJson) in json["images"] {
 if let url = subJson["url"].string {
    print(url)
}
}
```

If I understand correctly, my "images" JSON contains an array of dictionaries but my code is for an array of strings. What can i do to get an array of url strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your JSON

```
if let images = json[0]["images"].array {
  for image in images {
    if let url = image["url"].string {
      print(url)
    }
  }
}
```

The root object is an array `[]`, the dictionary (`{}`) containing `images` is in the first object of the root array.

You can get an array of the URLs with

```
if let images = json[0]["images"].array {
  let imageArray = images.flatMap{ $0["url"].string }
  print(imageArray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I also want a string of `url`? How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand, the value of `url` **is** `String`.

Comment: When I do this `let imageString = images.flatMap{ $0["url"].string }` I get a 'flatmap produces ... not the expected contextual result of type String!" Sorry. I'm very new to swift.

Comment: You wrote: *get an array of url strings*. This **is** an array of strings (`[String]`), not a single string (`String`).

Comment: I understand. Your answer worked perfectly and I already used it. But now I have another JSON that I need to parse. It requires me to get it out as a single `String` not a `[String]`. I do not know how to do this and I thought you might so thats why I commented to ask.

Comment: Ask a new question or edit this question adding the JSON and the expected result.